# Postive and Negative Validation Check is Not Working In Django Forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am working this validation check in django , i have to check postiva values. I have values a,b,c,d if (a,b) also (c,d) positive value will not allowed, i wrote the code this way but do not know why is not checking the validation.

I am working on django forms.py

```
for i in range(count):
        a = int(self.data.get(f'runtime_set-{i}-a') or 0)
        b = int(self.data.get(f'runtime_set-{i}-b') or 0)
        c = int(self.data.get(f'runtime_set-{i}-c') or 0)
        d = int(self.data.get(f'runtime_set-{i}-d') or 0)
        if a ==b==c==d==0:
            continue
        if (a + b) > 0 and (c + d) > 0:
            raise ValidationError(
                "When A  '{a}' , B '{b}'  is postive then  C '{c}' and d'{d}' positive    value is not allowed  ")
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do `if (a + b) > 0 and  (c + d) > 0:`?

Comment: @allexiusw yes, that was a type mistake

Comment: I added that as solutino so you can mark as that answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment that I made the problem was that you have the following boolean expresion:

```
if (a + b) > 0 +  (c + d) > 0:
```

So change to this to solve the problem:

```
if (a + b) > 0 and  (c + d) > 0:
```

Comment: it did not worked

Comment: Are you still having problems?

Comment: yes, i still have problems with this code.